# Scroll to the element id that is supposed to be loaded via Ajax (Infinite Scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scroll

So, I have two pages, `notifications` and `topic`. `Topic` page has comments, every comment has an unique id. When user presses on the comment link in the `notifications` page it takes him to the `topic` page that is scrolled to the exact comment user pressed on. The link after that looks something like `topic/titleoftopic#comment_627`. It worked pretty good, but now, when I have added infinite scroll and started showing only first few comments (rest of it is loaded on the scroll to bottom) it won't scroll to the comment and I receive an error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`, obviously this is because the comment is not loaded yet. Is there any way to make it work? I have an idea - start scrolling to the bottom until it finds the exact comment, but not sure how to implement this. Here is my code on how do I make it scroll:

```
//Scroll to the comment from notifications
$(document).ready(function() {
$('html, body').hide();

if (window.location.hash) {

    $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
    }, 800);

} else {
    $('html, body').show();
}
});
```

Thanks everyone for any advice or suggestion!

Comment: $(window.location.hash).offset().top is your problem

Comment: Yes, I know, I got it from the error in console, but how do I fix this?

Comment: The point is that .offset() doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added items you have to find that id from whole document.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('html, body').hide();
            if (window.location.hash) {
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(document).find(window.location.hash).offset().top
                }, 800);
            } else {
                $('html, body').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! But can you provide any examples?